# AEM Sighly deletes the anchor links from the included html

Tags: aem, sightly

I'm newbie to AEM and Sightly. I tried including a html file using

```
<sly data-sly-include="header.html" />
```

In "header.html", I have many anchor links with relative path. On page render, the anchor links disappear and only text is visible on the page. When I tried giving absolute path, then it works. Not sure the reason behind this.

Your help on this will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code present in header.html to better understand the issue

Comment: The links most likely get removed based on the link checker. Can you post a snippet from your `header.html` and an example of HTML rendered in the browser?